# JPA: Using criteriabuilder to find entities: Attribute name different from annotation?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteria

I have a mysql database with employee information, each employee has a technical id as primary key. In MySQL to selcet row(s) matching criteria, i can just use to get the following statement (works)

```
SELECT * FROM database_test.employee WHERE fist_name='First1';
```

In Java i can also use this as a  native statement to get what i want (works):

```
        List<EmployeeEntity2> objects = m_em.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT * database_test.employee WHERE first_name='First1'",
            EmployeeEntity2.class).getResultList();
```

However, i wanted to use the Criteriabuilder to get the same result and later generalize it for multiple columnName=columnEntry selections.

```
public List<EmployeeEntity2> testNoParameter() {

    //Based on https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria

    CriteriaBuilder cb = m_em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<EmployeeEntity2> q = cb.createQuery(EmployeeEntity2.class);
    Root<EmployeeEntity2> c = q.from(EmployeeEntity2.class);
    ParameterExpression<String> p = cb.parameter(String.class);
    //Works
    //q.select(c).where(cb.equal(c.get("firstName"), p));
    //Won't work
    q.select(c).where(cb.equal(c.get("first_name"), p));        
    TypedQuery<EmployeeEntity2> query = m_em.createQuery(q);

    query.setParameter(p, "First1");
    List<EmployeeEntity2> results = query.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

Using "fist_name" - the column name annotation from the Entity - will yield the following java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with:

```
    Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [first_name] on this ManagedType [xx.xxx.database.EmployeeEntity2]
```

EmployeeEntity2 has "fist_name" annotation:

```
@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
@Override
public String getFirstName() {
    return super.getFirstName();
}
```

So "first_name" should exist, however (with some debugging) i found out that the attribute expected is for some reason "firstName" instead - which i have not defined/annotated - so where does it come from - and how can i use the column names actually defined in the database (column = "first_name")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use property name of entity (not column name) to use it in criteria builder so instead of

```
 q.select(c).where(cb.equal(c.get("first_name"), p));
```

use

```
 q.select(c).where(cb.equal(c.get("firstName"), p));
```

`CriteriaBuilder` is RDBMS schema agnostic, so you use your model (entities), not schema (table names etc).

In JPA you dont normally use SQL but JPQL. Equivalent of your SQL in JPQL would be something like

`"SELECT e FROM EmployeEntity2 e WHERE e.firstName='First1'"`

Both `CriteriaQuery` tree and `JPQL` string are transformed down to the same query tree later on (can't remember the name), so they both must comply to the very same rules.

Comment: Thank you, but where in my entity is "firstName" defined?     `@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    @Override
    public String getFirstName() {
        return super getFirstName();
    }`

(super is EmployeeImpl2 with m_strFirstName member - what is "firstName" based on since i cannot find this string in my code...)

Comment: It is due to Java Beans specification. In Java, if POJO is a considered a Bean it must have properties. Field is considered a property, when it is named `X` and containss pair of setter and getter named `setX` and `getX`. In such case, bean contains property name X. In your case, you are not using field annotation but getter annotation, so engine threats it as getter of property named the same as getter without `get` part and in camel case. So having `getMySuperProperty()` will result in having `mySuperProperty` path available in JPQL and query builder. It is commont mechanism not JPA specific

Comment: Thats quite a bit inconvenient, needing to look up setter methods (and then lowercase it, setFirstName to firstName) but its the answer i was looking for -> accepted & Thank you !

Comment: Back in a days, you indeed had to generate a lot of boilerplaye getter/setter code. IDE quickly started to support generation of such methods so you didnt have to do it by hand. Nowdays, you can use Lombok that will generate getter/setter for you directly in the bytecode - so you dont even see it in .java file and yet those are accessible (and code assisted) methods. Who know what improvements will come in future. Right now is not a problem and a matter of singe annotation.

Comment: I mean more, its inconvenient i cannot just look at the database columns and create my statements based on those. I use netbeans, but autogenerate my getter/setter too. But i would rather base my criterion on the DB column than on some Entity getter/setter names. Oh well, it works :)

Comment: That the point. You look on data model not on the database schema. What if you  change column name for whatever reason? You would have to rewrite every query and query builder that was using this column. Here, you just have to change content of @Column annotation. Moreover Java classes can extend other classes - and the same can be done with entities. Then, as an example, single entity might be composed of multiple tables using joins transparently - how would you want to maintain that using RDBMS schema? :)

Comment: @pstone By the way, if you want to avoid mistakes like the one above, misspelled property names, and having to 'look getters up', consider using the [static metamodel](https://thoughts-on-java.org/static-metamodel/) for your criteria queries